# Change Firebase Array Ref based on Localstorage

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

i am stuck on the following problem:

i have a select element were the user picks an option.
this option is saved to the localstorage.
now i want to use this stored value as path for a firebasearray.

basically it seems to work but i cant get the firebasearray ref to update without hitting reload.

my firebasearray factory:

```
.factory("MyFireFactory", ["$firebaseArray", "$localStorage",
  function($firebaseArray, $localStorage) {
var ref = firebase.database().ref('demodata/' + $localStorage.selectedoption);
return $firebaseArray(ref);
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the angular docs [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) if found out that
"...All services in Angular are singletons..." wich basically means if i understood it correctly that they only run once.
Wich in my case meant the i had to move my factory code to the controller so that the data from localstorage can be used.

my now working controller:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('demodata/' + $localStorage.selectedoption);
$scope.demoscop = $firebaseArray(ref);
```